# Python to search for line that starts with pattern dn and prints the next 2 lines with oteh sub patterns

Tags: python-3.x

I have a raw file which has some data, however i want some relevent data only, i want if the line startswith pattern `^dn` following the sub pattern `AccessFTPexpire` and `ftpUser` then print those line and skip / ignore other ones.

Below is my raw data file:

```
$ cat ftpdata
dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
dn: uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: T
dn: uid=test-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
ftpUser: Y
dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
dn: uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: Y
```

What i have tried as follows based on my understanding, but this is Just print eveything  ..

```
$ ftp_pasr.py 
prefix = ['dn', 'AccessFTPexpire', 'ftpUser']
fh = open("ftpdata")
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(tuple(prefix)):
        print(line)
```

> Answers based on the Expert Contribution & suggestions i have
>   concluded the two cods below opted and borrowed by `Noob` & `gboffi` as they are fitting into the requirement:

1) Based on re pattern suggest, i have used to read the data from file and converted the `List tuple` output into string and each resulted output segregated into a newline so, it may become more readable ..

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
#with open('ftpacc3', 'r') as f:
with open('ftpdata', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = f.read()
        #data = f.read().replace('\n', '')
        regex = (r"dn:(.*?)\ncdsAccessFTPexpire: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\nftpUser: (.*)")
        matchObj = re.findall(regex, data)
        for index in matchObj:
            index_str = ' '.join(index)
            print(index_str)
```

Resulted output ...

```
$ ./ftp_parse.py
   uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com 05/03/2017 T
   uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com 05/03/2017 Y
```

2) Now another excellent approach suggested by `gboffi` , which i have again used with file based approach and just placed `end='\n'` to give a space between each result outputs..

```
$/usr/bin/python
$ ftp_parse.py
import re
buffer = [[], [], []]
a, b, c = 0, 1, 2

f = open("ftpdata")
for n, line in enumerate(f):
    buffer[n%3] = line
    a, b, c = b, c, a
    if (n>1 and
            buffer[a].startswith('dn') and
            buffer[b].startswith('cdsAccessFTPexpire') and
            buffer[c].startswith('ftpUser')) :
        print(buffer[a], buffer[b], buffer[c], sep='', end='\n')
```

Resulted output ....

```
$ ./ftp_parse.py
dn: uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: T

dn: uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: Y
```

Comment: Could you please show what do you expect as your output?  lines 3,4,5 must be printed? lines 6,7 must be printed? lines 9,10,11 must be printed?

Comment: @gboffi, sorry for the delay , yes that's correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer in the hypotesis that you want to print only groups of ***three*** lines, the first beginning with `'dn'`, the second with `'AccessFTPexpire'` and the third beginning with `'ftpUser`

First, let's prepare for using your data

```
In [76]: from io import StringIO

In [77]: data = '''dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: dn: uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
    ...: ftpUser: T
    ...: dn: uid=test-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: ftpUser: Y
    ...: dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: dn: uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
    ...: AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
    ...: ftpUser: Y
    ...: '''

In [78]: f = StringIO(data)
```

Next, I'm going to use a 3-slots `buffer` to hold the last lines read and the variables `a`, `b` and `c` to keep references to the order of the lines in slots, with `a` always pointing to the oldest line and `c` always pointing to the newest one

```
In [79]: buffer = [[], [], []]

In [80]: a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
```

We count and loop on the lines of the file,
we put the current line into the `buffer`, in position `n%3`,
we update (by rolling) `a, b, c`,
if `n>1` the `buffer` is full, we check the three conditions
and possibly print the buffer's contents.

```
In [81]: for n, line in enumerate(f):
    ...:     buffer[n%3] = line
    ...:     a, b, c = b, c, a
    ...:     if (n>1 and
    ...:         buffer[a].startswith('dn') and
    ...:         buffer[b].startswith('AccessFTPexpire') and
    ...:         buffer[c].startswith('ftpUser')) :
    ...:         print(buffer[a], buffer[b], buffer[c], sep='', end='')
dn: uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: T
dn: uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com
AccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017
ftpUser: Y
```

Comment: gboffi, This is really been another great answer i see, i'll check it ,making the code read from the file .

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex.

I've made one for your case on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Yx4HMj/1)

Hope this helps.

Group 1 gets you the uid line.

group 2 gets you the date.

group 3 gets you Y or T.

```
import re

string = "dn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\ndn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\ndn: uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\nAccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017\nftpUser: T\ndn: uid=test-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\nftpUser: Y\ndn: uid=dev-ftp,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\ndn: uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com\nAccessFTPexpire: 05/03/2017\nftpUser: Y"

regex = (r"dn:(.*?)\nAccessFTPexpire: (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\nftpUser: (.*)")

matchObj = re.findall(regex,string)

print(matchObj)
```

This will get you the following output:

```
[(' uid=case_101,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com', '05/03/2017', 'T'), (' uid=case_201,ou=ftpusers,ou=applications,o=regg.com', '05/03/2017', 'Y')]
```

Comment: Noob, i tried that but it not printing anything , i have aded the same into my POST , please see if  this is correct

Comment: This regex will match for the file content as an entire string. Not line by line.
if the file is not too big you can read it into a variable and then use re.findall(regex,string).
I'll edit my answer to include the python code.

Comment: Thnx, i'll check and revert.

Comment: Noob, i'm reading the data from file as its huge, its only sample which i exposed in the post